# Eevee Evolutions: Glitch or Feature

Tags: pokemon-go

I play Pokemon Go and I have evolved 15 Eevees and they are all Jolteons. I wonder if this is a glitch or a Pokemon Go feature. I have known about the **Name Trick**, but I don't like using hacks or cheats to get something special. Is it that the first evolution you evolve for Eevee is the permanent evolution except you use the **Name Trick**?

Comment: No, they are not hardcoded to be all Jolteons, you are being just very unlucky.

Comment: @pinckerman That one talks mainly about evolutions in different ways and I don't think it's Pokemon Go

Comment: It's definitely PoGo, as you can see from the tag, and quoting one of the answers "the evolution is chosen randomly from the first set of potential eeveelutions (Vaporeon, Jolteon, Flareon)."

Comment: *I have known about the Name Trick, but I don't like using hacks or cheats to get something special* ... that's not hack or cheat in any way...

Comment: "Name Trick" is not a hack, but a hidden feature, based on the lore of the main series games. Also it is limited to single use per specific eeveelution, so you can't use it all the time. Other than random evolutions (Vaporeon, Jolteon, Flareon), all others require special conditions to complete: special lure, walking number of km, evolving at specific time of day, getting certain number of hearts, and can be rather cumbersome. The trick is really useful to complete level 42 requirement task where you need to evolve all the unique Eevee evolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chance. One in 4,782,969 players would have their first 15 regularly evolved Eevees become the same Eeveelution. Given that the game has far more players than that, it's actually fairly likely to happen to *someone*, you're just one of the very unlucky people who have had it happen to you specifically.

> I have known about the Name Trick, but I don't like using hacks or cheats to get something special

The name trick is neither, but it's best saved for use on shinies or hundos anyway since you can only use it once per Eeveelution.

Comment: Thank you, @Sellyme, I should have edited my post, I wanted to save the Name Trick for my hundo shiny eevee.